# Ebay ebaysdk-python - get error Code: 18000, Too many requests

Tags: python, api

i got this error

> 'GetOrders: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 18000, Too many requests. Short-duration threshold exceeded. You have exceeded the call threshold per second. Please throttle traffic for this call and then retry.'

I use ebaysdk-python lib, i fill all params and my code like

```
api = Trading(debug=True,token=token, appid="", certid="", devid="",config_file="/e_bay/ebay.yaml", warnings=True)
api.execute('GetOrders', {})
```

What i do wrong ?
Thx for help.

## Edit

When i request in this url https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/?index=0&api=developer-analytics&call=rate_limit__GET&variation=json i get info that  i have  but i nowhere see Trading ,

> {
>     "rateLimits": [
>       {
>         "apiContext": "api context test",
>         "apiName": "api name",
>         "apiVersion": "v1",
>         "resources": [
>           {
>             "name": "DELETE1",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 100,
>                 "remaining": 100,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-27T13:17:45.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 15
>               }
>             ]
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "GET1",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 100,
>                 "remaining": 100,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-27T13:17:45.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 15
>               }
>             ]
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "POST1",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 100,
>                 "remaining": 100,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-27T13:17:45.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 15
>               }
>             ]
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "PUT1",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 100,
>                 "remaining": 100,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-27T13:17:45.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 15
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "apiContext": "commerce",
>         "apiName": "translation",
>         "apiVersion": "v1_beta",
>         "resources": [
>           {
>             "name": "commerce.translation.translate"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "apiContext": "sell",
>         "apiName": "listingapi",
>         "apiVersion": "v1_beta",
>         "resources": [
>           {
>             "name": "createListingDraft",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 5000,
>                 "remaining": 5000,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-28T00:05:55.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 89999
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "apiContext": "sell",
>         "apiName": "logistics",
>         "apiVersion": "v1",
>         "resources": [
>           {
>             "name": "sell.logistics",
>             "rates": [
>               {
>                 "limit": 2500000,
>                 "remaining": 2500000,
>                 "reset": "2020-04-27T07:00:00.000Z",
>                 "timeWindow": 86400
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "apiContext": "sell",
>         "apiName": "recommendation",
>         "apiVersion": "v1",
>         "resources": [
>           {
>             "name": "POST"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "GET"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "DELETE"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "PUT"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   }

maybe this is a problem ?

## EDIT

This problem was about sandbox, as i wrote limit ws applicable to other endpoints, not getorders

Answer (score 0):

Below info from documentation.

You need to modify Your code a bit (1000 queries per 15 seconds), so maybe sleep for 15sec after each 1000: **time.sleep(15)**

Per (seller) user ID, no more than 1000 GetSellerEvents calls can be executed within any 15-second interval. If this call rate limit is exceeded at any time, the application making the called is blocked. Each time an application is blocked, the user/application must wait until the block is reset after 15 seconds. This short-duration call rate limit applies to all seller accounts, and sellers/developers cannot appeal or request for a higher limit.

Comment: But i made only one request, maybe i preapre wrong configuration?  but i cant find what is wrong

Comment: Looks like ebay's internal message. Try another time, maybe it's some kind of coincidence with other applications' requests.